# showDialog() is accessing old View => Error: Activity has leaked window [...]

Tags: java, android, showdialog

I am writing the app and I have the following scenario:
First i show an Acitivty and I show a ProgressDialog while loading data from a Server. I do the loading task in a Thread because I found this to be a solution so that the Dialog is shown correctly

```
showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD);

loadListThread = new  Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            service.execRequest();
            loadingFinishedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            MyActivity.this.dismissDialog(MyActivity.DIALOG_LOAD);
        }
    });
    loadListThread.start();
```

After the Thread is finished I notify a Handler. Again this is a solution I found for the problem to access Views in the activity without being in the Thread anymore

```
loadingFinishedHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            showList();
        }
};
```

After loading is finished, I check whether I received data correctly. If not, i want to show an error dialog:

```
showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR);
```

I call the dialogs with the onCreateDialog method

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogId){
    switch(dialogId){
    case DIALOG_LOAD:
        String message = getString(R.string.load);
        ProgressDialog loadDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        loadDialog.setMessage(message);
        loadDialog.setCancelable(false);
        return loadDialog;
    case DIALOG_ERROR:
        String message = getString(R.string.error);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(errorMessage);
        builder.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.ok), null);

        return builder.create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is the problem: If I change the Orientation of my phone while data is loading and an error dialog shall be created afterwards, I get this message

```
Activity [...] has leaked window [...] that was originally added here
```

I understand why this is happening. The View has been re-created, when i rotated my phone and showDialog() is obviously trying to access the old one. But I do not know how to fix it.

Does anyone has an idea?

**Edit:** solved it :-)
I found out that I can prevent my Activity from restarting on orientation change. I read about it in this article 
[Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

I declared in the AndroidManifest by adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

that i handle orientation changes by myself. These changes can now be handled with this method

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

But for my case it was not necessary to add any code!

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogId){
if(isFinishing()){
return null;)}...
```